# What is the difference between the Crafting achievements 'Like Stars In the Sky' and 'Perfect As Tears'?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Both of them ask for crafting each of the 4 different Radiant gems, I am very far from having a single one but they seem to be duplicates to me - are there any differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://d3db.com/achievement/i/perfect-as-tears

Is to do 1 perfect gem out of the 4. That's why they show you the same list as in the other achievement.

http://d3db.com/achievement/i/like-stars-in-the-sky

Is to do 1 perfect gem of every of the 4 types.

So basically, you'll get Perfect as tears first, and then do the same thing on every type of jewel. (ruby, emerald, topaz, amethyst)

Comment: I'm a bit confused because both of them have all 4 mentioned in the description with check boxes. Also, if you do a perfect gem you should get Radiant for that.

Comment: The key is that the achievement includes all 4 as criteria for Perfect as Tears, but as soon as you get any one of them it's done. It's so you don't need to craft, say, a Radiant Emerald specifically even though you don't use them.