# Difference between the achievements 'Radiance' and 'Perfect As Tears'

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Related: [What is the difference between the Crafting achievements 'Like Stars In the Sky' and 'Perfect As Tears'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70518/what-is-the-difference-between-the-crafting-achievements-like-stars-in-the-sky)

As per Fredy's answer in my earlier question, 'Perfect As Tears' actually just requires you to craft any gem to maximum level. If this is the case, then how is it difference from Radiance?

http://d3db.com/achievement/i/radiance

http://d3db.com/achievement/i/perfect-as-tears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiance is not the maximum level, Radiant Star is, that is the difference.

Wikwocket was kind enough to include a source link:

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem/

Comment: wow. I missed the blasted 5 min timer by freaking SECONDS. SERIOUSLY!?!? -.-

Comment: The whole gem hierarchy can be seen [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem/). Radiant is 5 from the top.

Comment: @Wikwocket why are you repeating my answer in a comment?

Comment: So e.g. Radiance is making a 'Radiant Emerald' vs Perfect As Tears being a 'Radiant Star Emerald'?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, will accept this later once I can do so.

Comment: @alok yes thats how I understand it.

Comment: @Ender I was providing further clarification. Obviously you answered the question, but I like to link to official sources when I can. In this case the battle.net page allows one to visualize the entire hierarchy, confirm your answer, and learn where to look for answers to further questions.

Comment: @wikwocket point made, ill include the link.